# Can a Java process read from a MS MessageQueue?

Tags: java, msmq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java and MSMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506022/java-and-msmq)

I have a windows/C# process written by another group that pumps messages in an xml format into a MS MessageQueue, and would like to be able to read them out with a Java Process. I'm fine with writing native code if necessary, but would really like an all java solution if possible. Any helps/pointers/tips/links are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://wikis.sun.com/display/JavaCAPS/Sun+Adapter+for+MSMQ) page seems to have the subject covered.

Comment: Excellent. Checking it out now.

Comment: That solution is specific for a CAPS server. Was hoping for something more generic and stand alone. +1 though for getting me on the right track.