# SendMessage from Java app

Tags: java, winapi, sendmessage

How do I send a message from a Java app to another app? In Delphi and C# we have the `SendMessage` api:

[SendMessage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But I was not able to find it on Java.

Comment: are you meaning MSMQ, maybe accesible via J++ (if still exists), that's MS reactions to the Websphere MQ, maybe I wrong ... implemented in NET Framework 1.1.xxx

Comment: maybe yes, for example here :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506022/java-and-msmq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is a platform-independent language. If you want to do something very platform-specific, you will have to call some native code. You can use JNI for that purpose. Also, you can check the following question for some other options: [How to use winapi functions in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172520/how-to-use-winapi-functions-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You have to make that kind of calls using JNI http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html

Answer (score 0):

What kind of message?

You can use [sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/), [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html), [HTTP](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets.html), CORBA - the implementation will depend on how you want to develop and deploy the clients and servers.

One common way to have apps talk to each other these days is using web services, SOAP or REST.  No one knows you're a dog on the Internet; no client knows the language you're written in if you're an HTTP-based web service.

Comment: Follow the link on my post and you will see. :)

Comment: I think there are better solutions than JNI.  You give up all the cross-platform benefit of Java with JNI.

Comment: From the question it is not clear whether OP has any control over the non-Java app implementation. If this is indeed a constraint, going native is the only, if unfortunate, choice.

Comment: @olaf I dont have control over the java app but I do have control over the non-java app.