# WCF NetMSMQBinding With non WCF Client

Tags: .net, wcf, netmsmqbinding

I have a query related to WCF netMsmqBinding.

Is it possible to consume a wcf `netMsmqBinding` by a non .Net Client? say a Java Client.

Comment: When you say consume a WCF `netMsmqBinding`, what do you mean? If WCF services consume netMsmqBinding, they read directly from MSMQ. If a client uses a `netMsmqBinding`, they write directly to it. Are you wanting to use WCF from a non-.NET client to write to MSMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MsmqIntegrationBinding to allow non .net clients over msmq.

However, to support java clients you need to bridge the java/msmq interop gap.

There are a few ways of doing this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506022/java-and-msmq)

Answer (score 2):

No - all bindings named 'net'* are not interoperable.

Comment: ohh I see. Thanks for such fast reply. Any Idea how can I achieve this. Actually I want a non .Net client to communicate with the WCF even when the WCF service is under maintenance.

Comment: I'd look through this table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx and decide based on your requirements :)