# Java and MSMQ on JDK 64bit

Tags: java, msmq

Well, this might have been asked several time before, but I am still in the search of a solution. I am using jawin to connect to MSMQ through my application which runs on JDK7. It works very well, however, jawin cannot run with JDK7 64-bit.

Is there any MSMQ library (free) for Java with JDK 64-bit compatibility?

**[EDIT]**

Ok. I forgot to add the details or searches I have already made. This is a possible duplicate of [Java and MSMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506022/java-and-msmq). I checked the libraries mentioned in the answer but nothing seems to be JDK 64bit compatible.

I have also found one: [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/%E2%80%8E). But it doesn't have good documentation. There are no sample examples to read/write from/to MSMQ using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stick with JDK 32-bit.